# Drag and copy range vertically from spreadsheet google

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want the range `A:A` changes to `B:B` , `C:C` when i try to drag & copy a formula vertically.

The only way i know how i could do this is by changing the formula manually but i don't want to do this because i have around 700 rows

Formula i'm using are ranges from another page

[image]

I want to copy the formula in many rows, but as you can see on the image i get the formula like in the left column. I want to achieve something like in the right column without having to modify the range manually.
(In this example i removed the = to show you the formula)

I tried excel way but it doesn't work by trying to create 2 line one with A:A and second line with B:B and than select both lines and drag to copy lower lines but it just keeps on copy both ranges over and over.

Comment: Cannot understand what you want, can you rephrase your question, and if possible add example data to your question?

Comment: should be clear enough with image right ?

Comment: Do the formula start in row 1 or 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=MATCH("*"&$B$2&"*",INDIRECT("Data!"&CHAR(64+row(A2))&":"&CHAR(64+row(A2))),0)
```

**CHAR(64+row(A2))** is the same as **CHAR(66)** which is **B**, as you drop it down, Char() increases by one so you get the next column. So **CHAR(64+row(A3))** is the same as **CHAR(67)** which is **C**

Comment: thx a lot that worked for me. I forgot to mention it didn't start at row 1 but row 2 i just changed values accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This formula should also work in cell A2:

`=IFERROR(MATCH("*"&$B$2&"*",INDIRECT("Data!"&ADDRESS(1,ROW())&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(Data!A:A),ROW())),0))`

I've set up an example sheet here: https://goo.gl/gyORkV

Comment: there's just one problem with your solution and it's that i don't have control of which row it starts